# angular selected option being ignored

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-hide="controller.sports.loading">
    <label for="sport">Sport</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">2</div>
        <select class="form-control" id="sport" ng-model="controller.team.data.sport">
            <option ng-repeat="sport in controller.sports.data" value="{{ sport.slug }}">
                {{ sport.title }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the modal bound is controller.team.data.sport.
If I look at that, it contains a sport slug (tennis for example).
But even when this is populated there is no selected option. I think that might be because of my **ng-repeat**. I am setting my value as the **sport.slug** but the text is set to the **sport.title**.

How can I get my selected option be based off the sport.slug?

Here is an example of the model:

```
var team = {
    loading: false,
    data: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Test',
        sport: 'tennis'
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show it in http://www.plnkr.co?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ng-options`

```
<select ng-model="controller.team.data.sport" ng-options="sport.slug as sport.title for sport in controller.sports.data">
</select>
```

EDIT: I messed up the order of sport.slug and sport.title in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

`<select ng-model="controller.team.data.sport" ng-options="sport.slug as      sport.title for sport in controller.sports.data"></select>`

Try to use angular functionality as much as possible always.